# Zend Framework paginator not working properly with GROUP BY..?

Tags: php, pagination, zend-framework2

I have following code :

```
$select = new Select('tier');
$select->group('tierGroup');


$resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
$resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Tiers());

$paginatorAdapter = new DbSelect($select, $this->tableGateway->getAdapter(), $resultSetPrototype);
$paginator = new Paginator($paginatorAdapter);
```

It works perfectly fine if i remove the group by clause but with group by it counts all the rows of table and show more pages than data.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: @GBRocks I don’t think so.. otherwise i would’ve posted the correct answer..!! Now am not working in PHP any more.. switched my stack.. if you find anything.. please post it as answer..!!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues talking about this problem, it seems that the adapter can't figure the number of rows returned somehow. You should use setRowCount() methods in your controller.

```
paginatorAdapter = new DbSelect($select, $this->tableGateway->getAdapter(), $resultSetPrototype);
$paginatorAdapter->setRowCount((int)trim($select->getCount()));.
$paginator = new Paginator($paginatorAdapter);
```

Hope this little hack will work for you

Comment: I am already using setRowCount but it just setting number of row per page and the last 2-3 pages showing no result. But if i remove group by it works fine..!!